# Update every item in MongoDb usimg expressjs,mongoose,body-parser?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, body-parser

i have two files for interaction with Database.I have used expressjs, mongoose and body-parser.My database has three fields text, key and status. I want to update status of all entries in database. How can i update achieve this?

I am thinking to delete all the entries and create again all entries.May be thats not the proper way

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var cors = require('cors');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

Items = require('./items.js');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/taskDb');
var db = mongoose.connection;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send('Visit /api/*****');
});

app.get("/api/items", (req, res) => {
    Items.getItems(function (err, items) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        res.json(items);
    });
});

app.post("/api/items", (req, res) => {
    var item = req.body;
    console.log(item + "item post");
    Items.addItem(item, function (err, items) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        res.json(items);
    });
});

app.post("/api/items/complete/", (req, res) => {
    var item = req.body;
    console.log(item + "item post");
    Items.addItem(item, function (err, items) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        res.json(items);
    });
});


app.delete("/api/items/:_key", (req, res) => {
    var key =req.params._key;
    Items.deleteItem(key, function (err, items) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        res.json(items);
    });
});

app.delete("/api/items/", (req, res) => {
    var status = "completed";
    Items.deleteItems(status, function (err, items) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        res.json(items);
    });
});

app.put("/api/items/:_key", (req, res) => {
    console.log(key);

    var key = req.params._key;
    var item = req.body;

    Items.updateItem(key, item, {}, function (err, items) {                                
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        res.json(items);
    });
});

app.listen(3005, () => {
    console.log('Listening on port 3005...');
});
```

items.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var itemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    text: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    key: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

var Item = module.exports = mongoose.model('item', itemSchema);

module.exports.getItems = function (callback, limit) {
    Item.find(callback).limit(limit);
}

module.exports.addItem = function (item, callback) {
    Item.create(item, callback);
}

module.exports.deleteItem = function (key, callback) {
    var query = {key: key};
    Item.remove(query, callback);
}

module.exports.deleteItems = function (status, callback) {
    var query = {status: status};
    Item.remove(query, callback);
}

module.exports.updateItem = function (key, item, options, callback) {
    var query = {key: key};
    var update = {
        text: item.text,
        key: item.key,
        status: item.status
    }
    Item.updateOne(query, update, {}, callback);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For update all entries in  your collection you can use the **update** function with the option **multi:true**.

Here the mongoose documentation: [Updating Documents](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html)

In your case I tested with 3 items:

[image]

And I executed the command:

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');

  var ItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    text: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    key: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    status: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  });

  var ItemModel = mongoose.model('Item', ItemSchema);

  ItemModel.update({status:'A'},{$set:{key:'update key'}},{multi:true}, function (err, items) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    console.log(items);
  });
```

Here you can see that all the items with **status='A'** were updated to **key:'update key'**:

[image]